# How to Allow Duplicate Contacts when Saving on Overridden Contact Edit Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, contact, page-override

I am creating a Visualforce page that will override the Contact New and Edit pages.

I know that when a duplicate (based on Email or SSN) Contact is saved from the standard Contact page, the user has an option to Save (Ignore Alert).

[image]

How would I be able to duplicate that behavior on my overridden page?

Right now I get this error and haven't found a way to duplicate the behavior of the standard page to allow saving of the 'duplicate':
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Apex controller for your page and set DML options for insert:

```
Database.DMLOptions optionsForInsert = new Database.DMLOptions();
optionsForInsert.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;

List<Database.SaveResult> ans = Database.insert(toInsertList, optionsForInsert);
```